# The number of times print() was executed in the Dart for loop is incorrect

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing Dart code on my computer. As a result of executing the print() in 10,000 times for loops, it was printed only about 7,000 times instead of 10,000 times. But as you can see from the code below and the photo, the loop has certainly been executed 10,000 times. Why is this?

```dart
  checkPrint() {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      print("a");
      count++;
    }
    print(count);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the IDE you're using has some sort of limit on console message length limit. Nothing else.

Comment: but when I change the number to 100000 , the result is 
79614 I/flutter (12325): a   ...
If the number is small like 300, it will print 300 times even if hit it repeatedly, so is there a possibility that the speed is limited?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of VS Code on my M1 Mac Pro and I am not having such an issue.

Comment: I'm using vscode debug console on m1 mac air ...

Comment: Apparently it's caused by Flutter, not Dart. If I just run the Dart code, it will be printed 10000 times. Finally, I solved it by import'dart: developer'; and using log ().thank you !!

Comment: I even tried the same using Flutter but I didn't face the issue. Maybe it might be due to hardware specs, I don't know !!